# BOOTMGR image is corrupt fault while dual booting Ubuntu and Windows7

Tags: dual-boot

I have Ubuntu Precise beta 2 and Windows7 set up to dual boot.

The set up had been perfect, until today, with a black screen presented when trying to boot Windows with a *BOOTMGR image is corrupt, cannot boot* fault.

Is there any way to fix this from Ubuntu, or is a reinstall my only option?

Answer (score 1):

You can always rescue a broken Ubuntu boot by going back to your installation media. (Either a LiveCD or a LiveUSB). Booting up to that will place you in a working Ubuntu environment where you can attempt to fix whatever is preventing the system from booting.

There is a utility called Boot Info Script that will gather all the relevant info and save it to a text file. There is a walk through [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1291280). You can then copy this to pastebin or otherwise so we can tell you what you need to do to fix your boot.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest booting into live media, be it in the form of USB or CD/DVD to enter a working desktop environment, although I have not had any experience with Boot Info Script and would suggest that, if you have problems with it, you should give "Boot repair" a go. Once in a working desktop environment and connected to the internet, run these commands to install "Boot Reapir":

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

And then this one:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Once this has completed, if you feel confident, have a go with the software and see if it can fix your issue.

For more information and guidance visit the link below.

EDIT: After re-reading your question it seems that your issue is with the Windows side of things. I have had the same issue before and found a solution online somewhere, although I cannot remember it, I do remember that you can access a cmd using the Windows 7 installation disc and visiting the repair option. A google search might come up with a solution using the command prompt.

[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of but I couldn't remember the name. This one is pretty useful.

Comment: hey, yes the issue is with windows 7 booting rather than ubuntu which is fine, i haven't got the windows 7 install disc/repair disc to hand, so I was hoping if at all possible it could be repaired from within ubuntu?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know little about repairing Windows, other than trawling through forums looking for other people that have the same issue as me, I tend to just end up booting into live CD and recovering my files and reinstalling. But without a disc I don't know what you could do, the answer below seems to suggest how you can retrieve information that experts can use to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Also this may be a useful time for you to get into Ubuntu, give it a month and you might even not want to go back!

Comment: @RossFleming haha thanks mate, but I've been using ubuntu for years :) top marks for you being a supporter tho! :) like most I only dual boot because of certain apps, music production apps I can't live without :(

Comment: Ha ha, I know the feeling :(

Comment: If you do get a hold of an recovery disk for windows then the commands you need are `bcdedit /f /delete {bootmgr}` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. The recovery disk can be made by anyone with a Windows computer with the same OS version as you. Type `repair` into the Windows 7 search bar.

Comment: @Huckle thanks I'll look into it today, I assume after doing this that it will overwrite grub will it?

Comment: No, the bootmgr is under C:/boot in Windows (actually that can be changed, but it is generally in a folder called boot). Grub launches a stage 1.5 boot loader which reads the bootmgr (which is a stage 2 bootloader) and executes it.

Comment: awesome, ill get back to you with the results, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

The answer for you(sorry 'cause i speak english not well):
+ Try to boot with Mini XP(or others same it) on USB bootable.
+ Use bootice(you can download at :www.bootice.narod.ru) to backup current mbr of the hard disk
+ Use bootice again to change mbr to default mbr 6.x(find and boot the first active partition)
+ Now shutdown miniXP and reject USB. Power on and your pc will booting with only Windows 7
+ **After your log on to win7, the bootmgr will be fixed. Use bootice to restore the mbr that you backup**.
Now restart system and see what's happened.